# Mockito used with Kotlin is not working since it is still calling the original methods

Tags: gradle, kotlin, intellij-idea, mockito

When I use Mockito with Kotlin it seems that the mocking does not work. I doubled checked if I use the Mockito API the right way and also debugged and saw the mocked object has the Mockito interceptor/proxy and is not just a plain instance.

**Here is my minimum example:**

```
import java.nio.file.Path

class MyApp(
    private val downloader: Downloader
) {
    fun useDownloader(): String {
        val fileName = downloader.getFileName("fromUrl")
        downloader.download("http://notworking", Path.of("notworking:$fileName"))
        return fileName;
    }
}
```

```
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers
import org.mockito.Mockito
import java.nio.file.Path

class MyAppTest() {
    private val mockedDownloader: Downloader = Mockito.mock(Downloader::class.java)
    private val myApp: MyApp = MyApp(mockedDownloader)

    @Test
    fun testDownloader(){
        Mockito.`when`(mockedDownloader.getFileName("fromUrl"))
                .thenReturn("testFileName.pdf")
        Mockito.doNothing().`when`(mockedDownloader).download(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.any(Path::class.java))
        assertThat(myApp.useDownloader()).isEqualTo("testFileName.pdf")
    }
}
```

The error I receive is the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute

    at java.base/java.net.URL.fromURI(URL.java:681)
    at java.base/java.net.URI.toURL(URI.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.createRequest(SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.java:145)
    at org.springframework.http.client.support.HttpAccessor.createRequest(HttpAccessor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:677)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.headForHeaders(RestTemplate.java:369)
    at fcse.mycompany.importer.app.Downloader.getFileName(Downloader.kt:19)
```

The error tells me that the `Downloader` object was not mocked but used with its original methods - no interception happened.

Additional Infos:

- Using IntelliJ IDEA
- Using Gradle
- Running by IDE Test Runner (not the gradle one)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```kotlin
Mockito.`when`(mockedDownloader.getFileName("fromUrl"))`
```

use

```kotlin
Mockito.`when`(mockedDownloader.getFileName(ArgumentMatchers.eq("fromUrl")))
```

or

```kotlin
Mockito.`when`(mockedDownloader.getFileName(anyString()))
```

Comment: that almost worked besides the fact of:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArgumentMatchers.eq("fromUrl") must not be null`. A very confusing error message